# New object based on string, is it bad practice?

Tags: php, object

Consider this code:

```
public function setLoggers(array $loggers) {
    foreach($loggers as $logger) {
      $logger = new $logger['class']($logger['config']); // This line
      if( ! $logger instanceof LoggerAbstract ) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Logger '.get_class($logger).' must implement LoggerAbstract');
      }
      $this->loggersInstances[] = $logger;
    }
  }
```

Would you say its a bad practice? If so, what other way can I instantiate objects that I don't know its name before?

Comment: The only way I see this being a bad practice is if the user can influence `$logger['class']`. If all elements in `$logger` are controlled by you and do not rely on outside data, you should be safe.

Comment: @castis: Perhaps, but "safe" does not imply "good", although the opposite is usually true. This code is still hard to test, and not very flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things you could do.

1. Instantiate the loggers elsewhere, and pass them right into the method, without having to use the `new` keyword inside of the method. That is known as Dependency Injection. Depending on your class, it may be the best solution (I like to separate object instantiation from business logic).

   Basically:

   ```
   public function setLoggers(array $loggers) {
       $this->loggerInstances = $loggers;
       //Maybe some error checking.
   }
   ```
2. Use a `LoggerFactory`, which is able to create loggers and return them. This abstracts the need to use the `new` keyword, and allows for seams to test easier. The factory is, of course, an argument to the method, and as such uses Dependency Injection as well.

   Basically:

   ```
   $logger = $loggerFactory->build($logger["class"], $logger["config"]);
   ```

   And have the LoggerFactory have the `new` keyword + error handling and whatnot.

---

### Why are methods with the `new` keywords harder to test?

#### The short answer:

It tightly couples your method with external classes

#### The longer answer:

When you have a `new` in your method, the method will link to the class you want to instantiate, and instantiate it. This means that the method **needs to know** the class. When using a factory, the method **does not need to know** the class (it knows the name you asked for, but it doesn't need to actually start the class), and instead, you have a factory, whose job is to know the objects it's instantiating.

Now, as for the testing, imagine a test method:

```
public function setLoggersTest() {
    $logHandler->setLoggers(["Logger", "OtherLogger"]);
}
```

This actually requires "Logger" and "OtherLogger" to exist in the test context, for the test to pass. This is undesirable. Each test should only test a single unit of the app (that's why it's called "Unit" testing).

However, by passing and using a factory

```
public function setLoggersTest() {
    $logHandler->setLoggers(["Logger", "OtherLogger"], $mockLoggerFactoryCreatedByTheTest);
}
```

I can mock a factory within the test, and have it return whatever I want, making sure that the test is not dependent on the existence of this or that class.

Comment: Small observation: that would actually be an abstract factory, so `AbstractLoggerFactory` would be a more appropriate name for it.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate some examples on why would it be harder to test. I am doing this on Yii Framework and in the config for Logger component, I am specifying which loggers I want, thats why they come in string format (I can't instantiate at that moment). Are you saying that I should split it in one more class that actually creates and returns Logger objects? Thanks

Comment: @Jorge: Explanation added. Basically, your method should not be responsible for creating the objects, only saving them inside of a property on the class (i.e. "setting" the property).

Answer (score -2):

I've done similar things in C#. This is a common practice called `Inversion of Control` / `Dependency Injection`.

Using this will make your code more flexible and less likely to change. The downside includes an extra performance hit and increased complexity.

That should be true for C#. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I think it should be similar. If you search for "PHP Dependency Injection", you may find what you're looking for.

Comment: Krasimir Tsonev uses this technique in his tutorial [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-Injection-in-PHP-example-how-to-DI-create-your-own-dependency-injection-container)

Comment: IoC and DI are **not** patterns.

Comment: @tereško Can you please explain what you mean when you say they are not patterns? If I understand this correctly, [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) seems to indicate that they could be categorized as a software design pattern. If I'm mistaken, I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: DI (do not confuse with DI containers) is practical application of IoC methodology. DI is not a pattern but a practice. It' not even exclusive to OOP.

Comment: @tereško I think this is more a semantic issue. I said pattern, thinking that [patterns are formalized best practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). I'm using the terms pattern/practice/technique interchangeably, but I probably really meant practice. I'll update my answer to prevent confusion. Thank you, I think I understand it a bit better now. I've never considered DI outside of OOP.